# rsync two local absolute paths on the remote machine?

Tags: ansible

Ansible version and OS info:

```
ansible 2.5.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/naftuli/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/naftuli/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/naftuli/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

It's elementary OS Loki, which is Ubuntu 16.04, running kernel 4.13.0-38-generic.

[One interesting issue reported to me](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-rust-dev/pull/13) in [one of my Ansible modules](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-rust-dev) was that the `synchronize` task was failing for a user executing the role on a remote machine.

Since I have always been using `connection: local` for applying things on my own machines, I didn't encounter this until it was reported to me.

The task was defined as so:

```
- name: sync man pages
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ rust_user_home }}/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man/man1/"
    dest: "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
  become: true
```

Since I was always running locally, the "remote" machine was the same as the local machine, so this worked great; [according to the module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) with the above code, `src` will be copied from the local host to `dest` on the remote host.

I then made the change in that PR to this:

```
- name: sync man pages
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ rust_user_home }}/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man/man1/"
    dest: "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  become: true
```

However, now when running locally, Ansible attempts to SSH into my local computer. It's difficult to find a way to do the following with `synchronize`:

```
rsync -a /src/dir/ /dest/dir/
```

How can I approximate this behavior using the `synchronize` module?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was able to find a way around it using the un(der)documented `ansible_connection` fact:

```yaml
- name: establish connection type
  set_fact:
    is_connection_local: |-
      {%- if ansible_connection == "local" -%}
        true
      {%- else -%}
        false
      {%- endif -%}
- name: sync man pages (local)
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ rust_user_home }}/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man/man1/"
    dest: "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
  when: is_connection_local
  become: true

- name: sync man pages (remote)
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ rust_user_home }}/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/man/man1/"
    dest: "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: not is_connection_local
  become: true
```

If connected remotely, it uses delegation to run in the right place, if local it just uses the local filesystem as expected.